# Delta correlated white noise

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, brownian-motion

I am studying [Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), specifically [Langevin equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation). This equation includes a force expressed by a white noise, say $\xi(t)$. One of the hypothesis is that it is $\delta$-correlated (since it is a white noise). This is usually written as:
\begin{equation}
\langle\xi(t)\xi(t+\tau)\rangle=\sigma^2\delta(\tau)
\end{equation}
Where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). But I have problems with this "Dirac-delta".

Two deductions are made from the equation above.
On one hand, we can compute the spectral density of $\xi(t)$:
\begin{equation}
S_\xi(\omega)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \langle\xi(t)\xi(t+\tau)\rangle e^{i\pi\omega\tau}=
\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \sigma^2\delta(\tau)e^{i\pi\omega\tau} =\sigma^2.
\end{equation}
This result is clear, from the  definition of $\delta$.

But, on the other hand, let evaluate the autocorrelation in $t=0$. This is, setting $\tau=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\langle \xi(t)\xi(t+\tau) \rangle|_{\tau=0}=\sigma^2\delta(0) =\sigma^2.
\end{equation}

Both results seem suitable , however, I don't understand these two definitions of $\delta$. Specifically, I don't understand how explain that first $\delta$ works as a true Dirac-$\delta$ while then it works like a indicator function. Strictly speaking, $\delta(0)=\infty$, isn't it?

Summarizing, I need a way to explain why both calculus are correct. Or, if they are not, an explanation.

Comment: [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem)

Comment: I know this theorem. In fact, today I've been working on it. I know the integral equality stems from Wiener-Khinchin theorem. The problem is the third equality, when $\delta$ works as a indicator function. How can $\delta$ have two meanings at the same time? Or what is wrong in my explanation above?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have three lines of equations in your post. The first one more or less defines "white noise" as you sort of say yourself in the post. The second line uses the first one to do an integral. The third line has no $\delta$ in it at all, so I don't know what you mean when you say that in the third like $\delta$ acts as an "indicator function". All of that said, where did you get that third line?

Comment: Sorry, I should explained it better. I edited the third equation in order to make it more understandable. The question is: if $\xi(t)$ is $\delta$-correlated, then $C_\xi(\tau)=\sigma^2\delta(\tau)$. What happens with $C_\xi(0)$?

Comment: @CarlesPérez Your third equation is incorrect, as given. Rather, you should have $C_\xi(0) = \infty$ since $\delta(0) = \infty$. The question is still not clear to me: exactly why you are confused?

Comment: Thanks for all yours answers. I know that matematically a infinity is obtained. This is the problem because as far as I know, the autocorrelation function evaluated in 0 should be the variance, shouldn't it? So, the problem is the interpretation of a delta-correlated force. It means that its variance is infinity? The problem arises from Langevin equation, where the force is assumed to be a white noise. The autor of the article I am reading uses both of equalities I wrote in the first post.
Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: I foud here a very similar question, but it do not solve my problem... http://math.stackexchange.com/q/338064/

Comment: In your third line you have essentially assumed $\delta(0)=1$, which is false.

Comment: DanielSank, I agree with you. However it is not supposed that the autocorrelation function evaluated at zero has to be the second order moment (or assuming mean 0, the variance)? Then the variance is infinity?

Comment: Yes, the average of $\xi(t)\xi(t)$ is $\sigma^2 \delta(0)$, which you can think of as infinity. This is why purely white noise is non physical; it has infinite power.

Comment: It is good to think that $\delta(0) = T$, where $T$ is the "total time" (the limits of your integral).